# What does the green creep want?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

So, sometimes this room comes up in the **Shop** and there is this green creep asking me if he can buy something from me.

Does anyone know what he wants?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

these creep just wants items as weapons or passive items. if you drop one item just were he is,he will give you coins in return.
if you really need coins, break a chest, it can drop trash. giving the trash to the creep, you will get 3 coins.

Comment: Oh wow, sounds great thanks . How do you drop the item?

Comment: to drop a passive item, open the map and you will se you items   under it. select the item you want to drop and press Y.

Comment: Oh nice , cheers. Did you go past 2nd level ? :D

Comment: if you mean the second level of the gungeon, yes.

Comment: I think the amount of money he gives is random. I only got three casings for my junk, not 50.

Comment: @Fluttershy  could be random :/

Comment: I'm not sure, but nearly every time y gave him junk, he gave me a gold coin and some silver/bronce coins

Comment: Side note: The amount he gives you for Junk was nerfed in the 1.0.3 update.

Answer (score 3):

> The Sell Creep has a chance to appear in any normal shop. If items or guns are dropped on the grate, the Sell Creep will take them and give Coins in return.

http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Shop#Sell_Creep

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, which gate do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

There's also a special Sell Creep that shows up in his own room in Chamber 4. He'll pay you for items you drop down the grate like any other Sell Creep, but if you give him two items and a Master Round, he will

> disappear and open a door to the secret chamber "R&G Dept".